# A brick is 5 in x 5 in x 5 in. 250 of these bricks are stacked together. What is volume in cubic feet?

Tags: geometry

I got the volume for one brick as 125 cubic inches. I multiplied this by 250 and then converted to cubic feet and I think the answer is 18.1 cubic feet

Comment: You are correct (*though I would not have rounded, instead writing it as $18.08~\text{ft}^3$*)

Comment: That would still be a rounded answer :p @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz The original question states that each brick measures 5 in by 5 in by 5 in. This would typically indicate a precision of $\pm 0.5$ in.  If we want to get pedantic about significant figures, it might be best to track the error as it propagates.  If one does that, I would imagine that something near 20 cubic feet would be the most appropriate answer. ;)

Comment: On the other hand, one suspects that this is an exercise on some high school math assignment, in which case one should either give an exact answer (e.g. $(125\cdot 250)/12^3$ cubic feet), or provide enough of the decimal expansion for a grader to be confident that the student followed the correct procedure ($18$ or $18.1$ cubic feet is likely more than precise enough, given my expectation that the most common wrong answer would be around $1900$ cubic feet).

Comment: Think to people accustomed to metric system (about 90% on Earth, especially in scientific circles) : how many inches in a foot ?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the volume of a single brick is $5^3 = 125$ cubic inches, and thus a block containing $250$ of them will have $125 \times 250 = 31,250$ cubic inches. A cubic foot is $12^3 = 1,728$ cubic inches, and thus the volume of the block is

$$\frac{31250 \text{ in.}^3}{1728 \text{ in.}^3 / \text{ft.}^3} = 18.08449\overline{074} \text { ft.}^3 \approx 18.1 \text { ft.}^3$$

So yes, your solution is correct.